# Storing images and videos backend dev

Tags: python, mysql

I am working to try to create project with server side simple photo sharing. How do servers host images? Since SQL/Mongo DB's cant really hold (or aren't good for) holding images, how does image sharing work? Where do the clients store their images? How does it work on Instagram for example?

Comment: they're stored on disk and their path is stored in the database.

Comment: @thebjorn, so if I am running the server, it is stored on my computer??

Comment: Or you could store them in your Amazon S3 storage cloud. This is a really vague question and not appropriate for a Q&A site on programming.

Comment: But yes, the easiest solution is to store them in a directory on the computer running the server.

Comment: Where the disk is located is determined by factors such as traffic volume, access patterns, etc. In a directory on your server, S3, and dedicated SANs are all possible options.